# Socket Server Only Accepting MSG From Last Client Connected

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket

I currently have a sockets server that accepts connections from 4 different clients, saves them to list and then listens to the clients for when they press a button.

I can get all clients connected and stored into their designated slot in the list, however, when I go to listen to the clients, I can only listen to the last client connected.

When Connecting The Clients Get Stored In The Following:

```
c, addr = s.accept()  
CLIENT_LIST["red1"] = c
CLIENT_LIST["red2"] = c
CLIENT_LIST["blue1"] = c
CLIENT_LIST["blue2"] = c
```

This is done as the client sends a message with their player number, server reads it as 1,2,3,4 and then assigns them to the corresponding client list.  I have ensured this aspect is working as designed.

Then I start a while loop once all clients are connected that looks like this (Simplified)

```
msg= c.recv(1024)
print(msg)
```

However, only the last client connected is being listened to.

I have also ensured that I am able to send to the clients by spamming them in a while loop after all have connected by the following.

```
CLIENT_LIST["red1"].send('Red Team | Player One')
CLIENT_LIST["blue1"].send('Blue Team | Player One')
```

### Things I Have Tried

I have tried to specifically state all 4 clients that I would like to listen using recvfrom and also changing the c in c.recv to the client list name.  Neither of them are working.

I am assuming that when the next client connects it is over writing c and that is causing the issue.  But I thought I was getting around that by saving them to list.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am pulling my hair out.

Thanks!

### EDIT

After talking to Johhny below I have tried listening to the connection list as separate threads and it is working just fine:

```
def ListenForRed1():
    while True:   
        RedOneMessages = CLIENT_LIST["red1"].recv(1024)
        print(RedOneMessages)


def ListenForBlue1():
    while True:
        BlueOneMessages = CLIENT_LIST["blue1"].recv(1024)
        print(BlueOneMessages)

thread1 = Thread(target = ListenForRed1)
thread2 = Thread(target = ListenForBlue1)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Is there a way to do this without having to open 4 different threads and listening to them all at once?

Thanks

Comment: You need to `accept()` each client separately.

Comment: Hi Johnny,  I have already accepted all the clients separately.  Do I also have to listen to each client separately on a different thread after they connect?  If so, what was the point of me saving them to a list as I was told to do in the past?

Comment: In the code you have it appears you only call `accept()` once. You need to call it 4 times. Also, you need to call `recv` on each socket. This usually involves multi-threading. This answer has an example: [Python Socket Multiple Clients](//stackoverflow.com/a/40351010)

Comment: Sorry Johnny, I think you may be misinterpreting my code.  Like I had said, all of the clients connect just fine.  Once they are all connected I can also send to them just fine.  However, after they are all connected the server can only receive from the last connected client, still I am able to send to them all individually just fine.

The question is, why can I not specify to receive from a certain client I have declared in the list.

Comment: normally you would have to run it in non-blocking mode so `recv()` do't wait for data but it return empty string if there is no data so you can check next client. Or you have to use module `select` which can check if there are data in socket and then you can run recv or skip it. This way it doesn't wait for data and doesn't block loop. But probably it works only on Linux. So it can be easier to use `threads`